# Add meta title in spree product translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, spree

I am using spree2.3-stable, meta title is available in latest version,

I have added meta title for product spree , but when I click to translation it redirects to

> /products/product-name/translations

Where I can find this page to add one more field with name `Meta Title`

Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I have to refer [https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_i18n][1]

[1]: http://spree_i18n gem for it.

Comment: Please comment on the own answer and accept it, so that this answer shown under green(accepted answers). Thanks and Regards,